# How to make local home network on Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, server

so I wanna be able to access my files on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS machine from my other windows machine by typing its local IP address like this image

[image: this image]

but I don't know how to setup apache to display the folders I want, all I'm getting when I type my IP address in the other machine is the apache Ubuntu default page, so how can I make this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To access file system on remote server you can use SFTP to transfer file between systems.

Download Winscp : https://winscp.net/eng/download.php

Type your local ip address including username and password into setup then you can access your remote folders.